# Passing arguments to an executable using a batch file/command line

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

So there is a program someone wrote (that I don't have access to) that was written in C#, in which when I open it, it brings up a command prompt, asks several questions, and then returns an output.

What I want to do it write a batch file to automate entering all the arguments manually but nothing has really worked for me thus far. I tried "program.exe arg1 arg2.." in the command prompt and reading about the windows commands (I checked out ss64) but nothing seems to work.

So to summarize what happens is:

1) I open the program (a .exe file) in the command prompt (or click on it) where it asks me to enter a value or filename
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZsSi.png

2) I press enter to continue to the next question and the command asks me to answer another question (unless I finished the last one, in which case the program finishes executing and then closes).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqJ5M.png

Now, how would I go about making a batch file that enters SWAIN.dat, n, 1000, etc... automatically into this program? Again, I don't have access to the original program. i only know it was written in C#.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Here is an example of the "program.exe arg1 arg2.." approach http://i.stack.imgur.com/RsHWV.png

Comment: The program clearly doesn't take arguments, and is just ignoring anything you parse to it. You could write a VB script and use send keys - [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284201/schedule-a-vbs-file-to-run-in-windows).

Comment: I've posted an example for you.

Comment: Try `program.exe < data.txt` where `data.txt` is a file containing your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a VB script -

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "cmd" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.SendKeys "program.exe{ENTER}" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.SendKeys "SWAIN.dat{ENTER}" 
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "1000{ENTER}"
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
(
echo SWAIN.dat
echo n
echo 1000
echo etc...
) | program.exe
```

Comment: Program cannot start or run due to being incompatible with 64 bit Windows (which is weird because it runs well when I enter everything manually). I'll try it on another machine see how it goes.