# Batch one line to call an executable using arguments from file

Tags: c++, batch-file, command-line-arguments

For convenience, I have renamed all the files to simple names for my example.

I'm trying to **run an executable** (test.exe), with a C++ entrypoint `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` **from a batch file** (test.bat), and **pass arguments from a text file** (test.txt). The end goal is to run unit tests on an SDK using the testing software (test.exe).

My issue is that **I do not want to have to use a variable** when I call the executable since it makes the code harder to read :

```bsh
rem This works
set /p test_input=<test.txt& call test.exe %test_input%
```

After some research, I figured I should use **input redirection** like so :

```bsh
rem This does not work
call test.exe < test.txt
```

**This does not work, and I don't understand why.**

This is what I initially tried, and it has been suggested before on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418990/passing-arguments-to-an-executable-using-a-batch-file-command-line)).
I have access to the test.exe code, so I can print argc and argv :

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(new_argc >= 2)
    {
        if(strcmp("-help", argv[1]) ==0)
        {
            show_help();
            return 0;
        }
        for(int i=1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp("-framerate", argv[i]) ==0)
            {
                i++;
                if(i < argc)
                {
                    FrameRate = (float)atof(argv[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << "Parameters error" << std::endl;
                    return 0;
                }
            } else if ...
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter the arguments and parameters manually, it works as expected.

test.txt

```
-arg1 param1 -arg2 param2 ...
```

test.bat

```bsh
call test.exe < test.txt
```

Output : test.exe runs as if there are no arguments or parameters.

**Edit :**
Added a few details about the entrypoint and renamed the batch variable.

Comment: If you cannot, or will not, provide the exact execuatble file name and version information, it is impossible for us to offer a solution. Here we expect to be able to reproduce your issue, using made up names, and pretend argument strings does not assist us in replicating the issue, and as such your question is unanswerable without us all simply guessing. Please use the [edit] facility to bring your question up to standard, thank you.

Comment: `tmp` is a reserved variable name, specifying for some applications, a temporary files directory. Batch parses the entire logical line, substitutes for variables, then executes. In consequence, you cannot set and use a variable on the same logical line.

Comment: `set /P VAR=<test.txt & call test.exe !VAR!` will work, given that you started the console by `cmd /V:ON`; this is called [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Input redirection `call test.exe < test.txt` can't work when the executable expects an argument but not console input (as `set /P` does)…

Comment: @Compo, the question is about passing arguments as a parameter, I don't see why posting the details of an application is relevant. It is a C++ application with the standard "int main(int argc, char* argv[])" entrypoint. The first example with the usage of a variable works, but I don't know why the input redirection does not work. Maybe you could provide some links to more advanced documentation on input redirection, or a working example with "command < inputfile".

Comment: @Magoo Thank your pointing out tmp is reserved, I'll edit my code and the question.

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you for the details concerning delayed variable expansion. I'll look into changing the input parsing, I think that must be the problem.

Comment: @Compo, I understand better why you commented this now, once I've run my tests, I'll write an answer since as you have said, it is probably linked to the software and not the batch command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments under my question, I was pushed in the right direction.

**The problem was my understanding of `<`. It literally means "Read file to STDIN"** (as mentionned [here](https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/topic/7502/input-and-output-redirection)). Many other documentation sites give vague definitions like (as mentionned [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html))

> command < filename : Type a text file and pass the text to command

**I need to parse the input correctly**, since `stdin` isn't available in `argc` or `argv`, but through `std::cin`.

My batch code and text file remain unchanged, and I want to maintain the same form of parsing to avoid rewriting multiple projects, so I `split` the input string using the Solution 1.3 from [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/) (slightly modified) and created a `new_argv`.

```c
std::vector<char*> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter)
{
    std::vector<char*> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream(s);
    while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter))
    {
        tokens.push_back(_strdup(token.c_str()));
    }
    return tokens;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string extra_input; // Variable to store the contents of test.txt
    std::getline(std::cin, extra_input); // Recuperate the contents of test.txt
    std::vector<char*> new_argv = split(extra_input, ' '); // Split the args
    for(int i = argc - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        new_argv.insert(new_argv.begin(), argv[i]); // Add the original args to the beginning
    const size_t new_argc = new_argv.size(); // Create the new argc based on the final argument list (vector)

    if(new_argc >= 2)
    {
        if(strcmp("-help", new_argv[1]) ==0)
        {
            show_help();
            return 0;
        }
        for(int i=1; i < new_argc; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp("-framerate", new_argv[i]) ==0)
            {
                i++;
                if(i < new_argc)
                {
                    FrameRate = (float)atof(new_argv[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << "Parameters error" << std::endl;
                    return 0;
                }
            } else if ...
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    // Important, don't forget to free the memory used by the _strdup
    for(int i=1; i < new_argc; i++)
    {
        if(i >= argc)
            free(new_argv[i]);
    }
}
```

test.bat

```
call test.exe < test.txt
```

test.txt

```
-arg1 param1 -arg2 param2 ...
```

Of course, I need to add some checks to make it properly handle whitespace, but that's the gist of it. Thank you for your help and external point of view.

Edit : Fixed a mistake in the code.